# How to join tables without loosing rows that aren't in both of them?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: Artist and Artwork. Below is INNER JOIN on artist.name = artwork.artist

I need to list the cities that have more artworks made by male than by female.

[image]

First I find how many artworks made by male each city has:

```
select location, count(gender) from 
(artist inner join artwork on name = artist) 
where gender="male" group by location;
```

and get

[image]

Then I do the same but for female artists.

```
select location, count(gender) from 
(artist inner join artwork on name = artist) 
where gender="female" group by location;
```

Where do I go from here ?
I tried LEFT JOINing the tables that I get and SELECTing city from them WHERE male > female.

Like this:

```
select city_male from ( 

    (select location as city_male, count(gender) as male_art from (artist inner join artwork on name = artist)
    where gender="male" group by location)

    LEFT JOIN

    (select location as city_female, count(gender) as female_art from (artist inner join artwork on name = artist)
    where gender="female" group by location)

    on city_female = city_male

)
where male_art > female_art
;
```

Result I get is close to one that I need, but cities that only contain artworks of one gender are lost after JOIN.

How do I unite these tables into one and select the cities that have more artworks by male than by female ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
on city_female = city_male and male_art > female_art
```

If there is no match, you'll still get the city.

I think the query would be easier to write using `group by` and `having`:

```
select location as city_male,
       sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as male_art,
       sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as female_art
from artist inner join
     artwork
     on name = artist)
group by location
having sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) > sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end);
```